# Difference between <include.hpp> and "include.hpp"

Tags: c++, include

I am new to C++.

What is the difference between including the c++ header files using "" and <>

I am trying to use some of the header files form an open source library. All header files in that library are included using <>. Now when I do the same in my header file, its failing at compile time.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

<> looks firstly in the header path for the header file whereas "" looks firstly in the current directory of the file for the header.

Answer (score 11):

The distinction is very largely implementation defined; the `"..."` form
should look first in the place where the file which includes it is
situated; the `<...>` no.  Beyond that, both look in an implementation
defined list of places, with the additional requirement that if the
compiler doesn't find a `"..."` form in any of the expected places, it
reprocesses the include as if it were a `<...>` form.

In practice, all of the compilers I know build a list of places using 
the `-I` or `/I` options, followed by a number of "standard" and
compiler defined places.  This list is for `<...>`; `"..."` is searched
in the same directory as the including file, then treated as a `<...>`.
(Some compilers, at least, also have options to add to the list for
`"..."`.)

I'm not sure what's happening with regards to the library.  Normally,
when using a third party library, you have to add one or more `-I` or
`/I` options to tell the compiler where to find its headers.  Once
you've done that, both your code and the library code should find all of
the necessary headers.  The one case I can think of where an include
might work in a library header, and not in your own headers, is a
`"..."` style include in a library header which was included from
another library header, using a path specifier, e.g.:

LibraryFile1.hpp:

```
#include "Subdir/LibraryFile2.hpp"
```

LibraryFile2.hpp:

```
#include "LibraryFile3.hpp"
```

You will have told the compiler to look for the headers (using a `-I`
option) in something like `LibraryRoot/include`, which is where
`LibraryFile1.hpp` is located; `LibraryFile2.hpp` is relative to this
location, and in `LibraryFile2.hpp`, the compiler finds
`LibraryFile3.hpp` because it is in the same directory as the file which
includes it.  If you try to include `LibraryFile3.hpp` directly,
however, the compiler won't find it.

Answer (score 4):

File includes between `<>` are looked for in your compiler's path, whereas `""` is looking relatively to your current directory (or absolute if you specify a path that starts with `/` or `c:\` but this is not recommended)

On Unix systems, by default the path contains `/usr/include`. This path may be completed by adding `-Isome_directory` for it to search in it.

For example, if you have your file `test.c` and you want to include `include/test.h`, you have different choices:

- Write `#include "include/test.h"`, which will look relatively from the directory of the compiled file.
- Write `#include <test.h>`, but this time you will need to specify `-Iinclude` to the compiler to add the `./include` directory to the compiler's path.

Note, however, that some compilers accept the `""` notation for lookups in the path, but that always confused me and is a bad thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

The quotes mean include from local folder and the <> mean to include from another directory specified using a flag to g++ or MSVC or whatever compiler you are using or system headers.

Answer (score 2):

<> looks in the default directory for include files, "" looks in the current directory and than in the default directory

Answer (score 2):

This question is a duplicate of [Question 21593](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593).  None of the above answers above are totally correct.  Like many programmers, I have used the informal convention of using the "myApp.hpp" form for application specific files, and the  form for library and compiler system files, i.e. files specified in /I and the INCLUDE environment variable.  However, the C standard states that the search order is implementation specific.

Here's the [msdn explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4.aspx) copied here for your convenience).

> **Quoted form**
>      The preprocessor searches for include files in this order:
>      1. In the same directory as the file that contains the #include statement.
>      2. In the directories of the currently opened include files, in the reverse order in which
>         they were opened. The search begins in the directory of the parent include file and
>         continues upward through the directories of any grandparent include files.
>      3. Along the path that's specified by each /I compiler option.
>      4. Along the paths that are specified by the INCLUDE environment variable.
>
> **Angle-bracket form**
>     The preprocessor searches for include files in this order:
>     1. Along the path that's specified by each /I compiler option.
>     2. When compiling occurs on the command line, along the paths that are specified by the INCLUDE
>        environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Including a file using `<>` will tell the compiler to look for those files in environment-defined inclusion folders. Those folders can be standard system folders, or defined by your Makefile if you use one, etc. Using `""`, the compiler will look for inclusion files only in the source file's path.
So you can use `""` and use absolute paths or the path which is relative to the source file you try to include in, or you can use `<>` after defining your inclusion folders, and just specify the name of the header file to include.
IMHO, the second option is better, especially if you use a lot of headers, or multiple libraries, etc...

To define inclusion folders at compilation time : `gcc -I ...` ([man gcc!](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc))